# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type' with .Any

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Study this a moment: Consider a schema with a Person, GovernmentId, and GovernmentIdType tables. Andrew Tappert (Person) has two id cards (GovernmentId), one from Oregon (GovernmentIdType) and one from Washington (GovernmentIdType).

Now generate an edmx from it.

Now imagine you want to find all the people having a certain ID value, say 1234567.

This can be accomplished with a single database hit with this:

```
dbContext context = new dbContext();
string idValue = "1234567";
Expression<Func<Person,bool>> expr =
    person => person.GovernmentID.Any(gid => gid.gi_value.Contains(idValue));

IEnumerable<Person> people = context.Person.AsQueryable().Where(expr);
List<Person> people = peopleQuery.ToList();
```

This works.  Now why does the following result in this closure type exception...

```
dbContext context = new dbContext();
string idValue = "1234567";
Expression<Func<GovernmentId, bool>> gidExpr = gid => gid.gi_value.Contains(idValue);
Expression<Func<Person,bool>> expr =
    person => person.GovernmentID.AsQueryable().Any(gidExpr);

IEnumerable<Person> peopleQuery = context.Person.AsQueryable().Where(expr);
List<Person> people = peopleQuery.ToList();
```

**Edit**

Used version is EF 1 (.NET 3.5).

Comment: Does the second code really compile? I guess `person.GovernmentID` is a collection type like `ICollection<T>`, right? But then it is not an `IQueryable<T>`, but an `IEnumerable<T>` and `Any` does not accept `gidExpr` as an `Expression`. Only a `Func` would be possible. Can you double check, if this is exactly the code you are using and perhaps also show the relevant classes?

Comment: ahh, sorry, I forgot the .Compile() on that expression.  The classes are generated entity types and have nothing special about them.  gi_value is a column on the table as you would expect.

Comment: I've added info about your version (EF 1), quite important for your question.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain exactly why the second code doesn't work. But apparently there is a problem with using `Compile()` in this LINQ to Entities query. When testing the code I hadn't your exception but instead an "Internal .NET Framework Data provider error 1025".

The following though did work for me (applying `AsQueryable` to the `GovernmentID` collection so that you can use the expression directly without `Compile()`):

```
dbContext context = new dbContext();
string idValue = "1234567";

Expression<Func<GovernmentId, bool>> gidExpr =
    gid => gid.gi_value.Contains(idValue);

Expression<Func<Person,bool>> expr =
    person => person.GovernmentID.AsQueryable().Any(gidExpr);

IEnumerable<Person> people = context.Person.AsQueryable().Where(expr);
```

The `AsQueryable()` in the last line is redundant and can be removed since `context.Person` is an `IQueryable<T>` anyway.

**Edit**

Error reproduced with EF 1 (.NET 3.5). With EF 4.0 and EF 4.1 (.NET 4) it works.

Comment: I also go this internal error with .Compile (not the closure type exception).  Using person.GovernmentID.AsQueryable().Any(gidExpr) is what I want to do.  It compiles (c# compiler) and the .Where even returns a value, but when you call something like.ToList() on it, you get the closure type exception.  I will be excited to have someone else reproduce this!

Comment: @andrew: I had used `ToList()` and it works and returned the correct results. Perhaps you must complete your question with more code to make the problem reproducable.

Comment: I don't know what else to provide.  I run this very code with .ToList() tacked onto the end of the last line and it throws this exception.  Are you using EF3.5?

Comment: also, I can get it to work by passing in gid => gid.gi_value.Contains(idValue) into the Any method directly instead of using the gidExpr variable.

Comment: @andrew: No, EF 4.1 and 4.2. You could show the entity classes `Person` and `GovernmentId` with their essential properties. I even don't know what type `person.GovernmentID` exactly is.

Comment: i'm not sure if this will work, but try this link to a zip file in my gmail:   https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B77PmlunNuEpYjRiNzc5NGEtZDI1NC00MTZiLWExNmMtOGYzMzA0MzU4Mzlm

Comment: @andrew: Doesn't work unfortunately, I get an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error when I try to download (with Google Chrome).

Comment: @andrew: I have reproduced the error. See my Edit. I've changed the target platform in your project from 3.5 to 4.0 and it worked at once. I guess you must upgrade to .NET 4.

Comment: so is this just a bug?  This has implications for anyone using sharepoint 2007 or 2010, as neither use 4.0

Comment: @andrew: Possibly it's a bug in EF 1, yes. Or EF 4 supports now kinds of expressions which EF 1 didn't.